# Dynamic Operation Error with Plugin c# - Create Item without Dynamic Interop Outlook

Tags: c#, dynamic, plugins, outlook, office-interop

I am having an issue when uploading a plugin to another Application. I am getting the error "Dynamic operations can only be performed in homogenous AppDomain".  I have searched for resolutions and the answers found said to set the legacyCasPolicy to false. However, I can not make changes to the main program, and for whatever reason the application has this property set to true.
The error is being caused by the dynamic method Create Item, as shown below:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
MessageBox.Show(outlookApp.IsTrusted.ToString());

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.**CreateItem**(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
```

Is there a way to create the item without using dynamic methods? Any other solutions? Any help would be a lifesaver.

Comment: Why do you need to use dynamic methods?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid dynamic methods. The application i'm unploading my plugin to doesn't allow them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Application class from the Outlook object model provides the [CreateItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869635(v=office.15).aspx) method. You may find a sample code in the following articles written by me:

- [How To: Create a new Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/04/outlook-create-appointment-item/)
- [How To: Create a new recurring Outlook Appointment item](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/07/outlook-recurring-appointment/)

Comment: Using the CreateAppointmentUsingItemsAdd method from your howto solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: `ns = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");` is giving me an error on `OutlookApp`. It doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Just FYI: The golden thing of the function `CreateAppointmentUsingItemsAdd` is not that it would not use a dynamic return type, but that it does not do a direct cast. So: `var email = (Outlook.MailItem) application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);` does not work, but `var email = application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as Outlook.MailItem;` somehow does work.

Comment: PS: you can test this by adding to the app.config following data: `configuration\runtime\NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy@enabled=true`. For those who wonder why you would do such a thing? Nav 2017 has this in its config file, and a plugin writer can't just ask all his customers to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

CreateItem method is fine. It is the IsTrusted property that Outlook.Application object does not support.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to remove that. I was using that to see if it was a trust issue. The CreateItem method is what's throwing the error though because it's a dynamic method.